# JavaScript: Calculate the nth root of a number

Tags: algorithm, math, javascript

I'm trying to get the nth root of a number using JavaScript, but I don't see a way to do it using the built in `Math` object. Am I overlooking something?
If not...

Is there a math library I can use that has this functionality?
If not...

What's the best algorithm to do this myself?

Comment: How many of the roots do you want? Just the single most obvious, or all of them?

Comment: the obvious answers using Math.pow(x, 1/n) are down below the most upwards ones here - which I don't understand, because these homebaked algos dont offer anything new over the Math.pow usage. Also, for any n-th root that is multiple of 2 or 3 you can use Math.sqrt or Math.cbrt (which ananswer below mentions already), and chain-call them n times to get any 2^n or 3^n -th root (with n >= 1 obviously). or any other factorization, like the 6-th root would be the Math.sqrt(Math.cbrt(x)) for example (or the other way round, it doesnt matter).

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Can you use something like this?

```
Math.pow(n, 1/root);
```

eg.

```
Math.pow(25, 1/2) == 5
```

Comment: This will work if the pow function can take a fractional exponent. Not sure, but it _should_ :)

Comment: it does but does not handle negative numbers

Comment: A small note. The pow function approximates the answer. So, for large values, this approximation can return very wrong numbers. [[reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956471/wrong-result-by-java-math-pow)]. The same is true for the JS implementation. [ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.pow)

Comment: How to handle `Math.pow(-32, 1/5)`?

Comment: @QianChen Always make the *base* be positive (-32 ➜ 32). Then, if the *exponent* is odd (5, so yes), turn the *result* negative (2 ➜ -2)

Comment: it even works with `**` operator but the fraction needs to be in parentheses. `25 ** (1/2)`. This will work with BigInt.

Answer (score 32):

The `n`th root of `x` is the same as `x` to the power of `1/n`. You can simply use `Math.pow`:

```
var original = 1000;
var fourthRoot = Math.pow(original, 1/4);
original == Math.pow(fourthRoot, 4); // (ignoring floating-point error)
```

Comment: How about Math.pow(-32, 1/5)?

Answer (score 16):

Use Math.pow()

Note that it does not handle negative nicely - here  is a discussion and some code that does

http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/06/cube-root-an-beyond/

```
function nthroot(x, n) {
  try {
    var negate = n % 2 == 1 && x < 0;
    if(negate)
      x = -x;
    var possible = Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
    n = Math.pow(possible, n);
    if(Math.abs(x - n) < 1 && (x > 0 == n > 0))
      return negate ? -possible : possible;
  } catch(e){}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use

```
Math.nthroot = function(x,n) {
    //if x is negative function returns NaN
    return this.exp((1/n)*this.log(x));
}
//call using Math.nthroot();
```

Answer (score 9):

For the special cases of square and cubic root, it's best to use the native functions [`Math.sqrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt) and [`Math.cbrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt) respectively.

As of ES7, the [exponentiation operator `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) can be used to calculate the *n*th root as the <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*n*</sub>th power of a non-negative base:

```
let root1 = Math.PI ** (1 / 3); // cube root of π

let root2 = 81 ** 0.25;         // 4th root of 81
```

This doesn't work with negative bases, though.

```
let root3 = (-32) ** 5;         // NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

The `n`-th root of `x` is a number `r` such that `r` to the power of `1/n` is `x`.

In real numbers, there are some subcases:

- There are two solutions (same value with opposite sign) when `x` is positive and `r` is even.
- There is one positive solution when `x` is positive and `r` is odd.
- There is one negative solution when `x` is negative and `r` is odd.
- There is no solution when `x` is negative and `r` is even.

Since `Math.pow` doesn't like a negative base with a non-integer exponent, you can use

```
function nthRoot(x, n) {
  if(x < 0 && n%2 != 1) return NaN; // Not well defined
  return (x < 0 ? -1 : 1) * Math.pow(Math.abs(x), 1/n);
}
```

Examples:

```
nthRoot(+4, 2); // 2 (the positive is chosen, but -2 is a solution too)
nthRoot(+8, 3); // 2 (this is the only solution)
nthRoot(-8, 3); // -2 (this is the only solution)
nthRoot(-4, 2); // NaN (there is no solution)
```

Comment: "nthRoot(-4, 2); // NaN (there is no solution)"
well... at least not in real numbers

Comment: After seeing https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268374/205696 I found a few optimizations to `nthRoot`. Since `Math.pow(-4, 1/2)` returns `NaN` and since we only need `Math.abs` for negative numbers, we can use `Math.abs` only for negative **and** odd numbers (not sure the latter is an optimization). So in one line: `let nthRoot = (x, n) => n % 2 === 1 && x < 0 ? -(Math.abs(x) ** (1/n)) : x ** (1/n)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know this is an old question. But, based on SwiftNinjaPro's answer, I simplified the function and fixed some NaN issues. Note: This function used ES6 feature, arrow function and template strings, and exponentation. So, it might not work in older browsers:

```
Math.numberRoot = (x, n) => {
  return (((x > 1 || x < -1) && n == 0) ? Infinity : ((x > 0 || x < 0) && n == 0) ? 1 : (x < 0 && n % 2 == 0) ? `${((x < 0 ? -x : x) ** (1 / n))}${"i"}` : (n == 3 && x < 0) ? -Math.cbrt(-x) : (x < 0) ? -((x < 0 ? -x : x) ** (1 / n)) : (n == 3 && x > 0 ? Math.cbrt(x) : (x < 0 ? -x : x) ** (1 / n)));
};
```

Example:

```
Math.numberRoot(-64, 3); // Returns -4
```

Example (Imaginary number result):

```
Math.numberRoot(-729, 6); // Returns a string containing "3i".
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that tries to return the imaginary number. It also checks for a few common things first, ex: if getting square root of 0 or 1, or getting 0th root of number x

```
function root(x, n){
        if(x == 1){
          return 1;
        }else if(x == 0 && n > 0){
          return 0;
        }else if(x == 0 && n < 0){
          return Infinity;
        }else if(n == 1){
          return x;
        }else if(n == 0 && x > 1){
          return Infinity;
        }else if(n == 0 && x == 1){
          return 1;
        }else if(n == 0 && x < 1 && x > -1){
          return 0;
        }else if(n == 0){
          return NaN;
        }
        var result = false;
        var num = x;
        var neg = false;
        if(num < 0){
            //not using Math.abs because I need the function to remember if the number was positive or negative
            num = num*-1;
            neg = true;
        }
        if(n == 2){
            //better to use square root if we can
            result = Math.sqrt(num);
        }else if(n == 3){
            //better to use cube root if we can
            result = Math.cbrt(num);
        }else if(n > 3){
            //the method Digital Plane suggested
            result = Math.pow(num, 1/n);
        }else if(n < 0){
            //the method Digital Plane suggested
            result = Math.pow(num, 1/n);
        }
        if(neg && n == 2){
            //if square root, you can just add the imaginary number "i=√-1" to a string answer
            //you should check if the functions return value contains i, before continuing any calculations
            result += 'i';
        }else if(neg && n % 2 !== 0 && n > 0){
            //if the nth root is an odd number, you don't get an imaginary number
            //neg*neg=pos, but neg*neg*neg=neg
            //so you can simply make an odd nth root of a negative number, a negative number
            result = result*-1;
        }else if(neg){
            //if the nth root is an even number that is not 2, things get more complex
            //if someone wants to calculate this further, they can
            //i'm just going to stop at *n√-1 (times the nth root of -1)
            //you should also check if the functions return value contains * or √, before continuing any calculations
            result += '*'+n+√+'-1';
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please use a switch statement

Comment: with that many if statements, itll take longer to compute the function itself in high activity situations, so none of those checks will really matter at that point

Answer (score 0):

I have written an algorithm but it is slow when you need many numbers after the point:

https://github.com/am-trouzine/Arithmetic-algorithms-in-different-numeral-systems

```
NRoot(orginal, nthRoot, base, numbersAfterPoint);
```

The function returns a string.

E.g.

```
var original = 1000;
var fourthRoot = NRoot(original, 4, 10, 32);
console.log(fourthRoot); 
//5.62341325190349080394951039776481
```

Answer (score 0):

The ultra short version: const nthroot=(x,root)=>x**(1/root);

Answer (score 0):

[Image: calculate the nth root of a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o1x0.jpg)

To calculate the nth root of a number in JavaScript, you can use exponentiation. To find the nth root of a number x, you can use the following formula:
nth root of  **x = x^(1/n)**

power function (review):

```
Math.pow(base, exponent);
```

Now, to calculate the nth root of a number x, you can use this function as follows:

```
function nthRoot(x, n){
    return Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
}
    
let number = 27;
let root = 3;
let result = nthRoot(number, root);
console.log(result);
// result = 27^(1/3) = 3
```

Another example:

```
console.log(nthRoot(1024, 5));
// 1024^(1/5) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Math object doesn't have a built-in method specifically for calculating the nth root of a number. However, you can still calculate it using the Math.pow() method by taking advantage of the property that the nth root of a number x is equivalent to raising x to the power of 1/n.

For example, to find the cube root (3rd root) of a number x, you can do:

```
const x = 27;
const n = 3;
const result = Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
console.log(result); // Output: 3
```

If you are looking for a library that provides more advanced mathematical functions, you can use a popular JavaScript math library called "math.js". This library extends the capabilities of the built-in Math object and provides additional functions like nthRoot().

First, you need to include the library in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/11.7.0/math.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the nthRoot() function:

```
const math = require("mathjs");
const x = 125;
const n = 3;
const result = math.nthRoot(x, n);
console.log(result); // Output: 5
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
const original = 16;

const rootOf = 0.33;
const root = Math.pow(original, 1 / rootOf);
console.log(`${rootOf} Root of ${original} is ${root.toFixed(2)}`);
```

Comment: Does this answer improve on or add information beyond the other answers that were posted YEARS ago? It's a code dump of the same solution with no explanation...