# Javascript - Find the base of an exponential equation

Tags: javascript, algebra

I was wondering if anyone knew how to find the base of an exponential equation in Javascript.

I couldn't find any function that allows this to be done (e.g. using the Math functions).

For example, how do I find 'b' in the following equation:

```
y = b^t
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: do you know t and y beforehand?

Comment: `y = b^t <-> b = Math.pow(y, 1/t)`

Comment: or you can use log also

Comment: Sorry all, forgot to mention that you do know what 'y' and 't' are beforehand. Looks like @Miszy above has the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Calculate the nth root of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308627/javascript-calculate-the-nth-root-of-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what are the values of `y` and `t` are, you can get the value of `b` by calculating the **t-th root of y** like this:

```
Math.pow(y, 1/t);
```

Source: 
[JavaScript: Calculate the nth root of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308627/javascript-calculate-the-nth-root-of-a-number)

Comment: Genius! Thanks mate, that was exactly what I was after. After a day of coding and then getting to this equation it was giving me a headache. Thanks @Stasel for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is math and the logarithm.

```
   y = b^t
=> t = log(y) / log(b)
=> log(b) = log(y) / t
=> b = 10 ^ ( log(y) / t )
```

So it would be something like

```
b = Math.pow(10, (Math.log(y) / t));
```

-Hannes

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I tried the final equation but it was coming up with some funky results.