# How do you convert a variable expression to executable code (not to substitute values in)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a personal project right now ( I'm trying to plot a graph with the given expression in javascript), and I'm facing an issue.

Say `s = "3x^2+4x+5"`, I'm trying to convert this into `return 3*x*x + 4*x + 5`, in the function

```
myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
    return 3*x*x + 4*x + 5;
}, 'green', 3);
```

I've looked around and I came across `eval()`, but it needs to substitute a value into `x`. Other guides say that I need to make my own parser, but how do you create a parser that does the above?

Currently I have a function to convert `s = "3x^2+4x+5"` into `["+3x^2","+4x","+5"]` into `["+3*x*x","+4*x","+5"]`, if that helps.

(Sorry for the multiple edits)

Comment: Are you always dealing with polynomials of a similar type?

Comment: Yes, once I handle this I'm hoping to handle cubic and trigo functions

Comment: To do anything of reasonable complexity you'll need to write/use some kind of parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the expression parser of [math.js](http://mathjs.org) for this, it supports defining functions:

```
var f = math.eval('f(x) = 3x^2+4x+5');
console.log(f(1)); // outputs 12
console.log(f(2)); // outputs 25
console.log(f(3)); // outputs 44
```

math.js has it's own expression parser, it does not use JavaScript's `eval` function.

Answer (score 1):

> > if you have this ["+3*x*x","+4*x","+5"]

Than you can do something like below to evaluate.

```js
// Code goes here

function myFunction(){
  //alert('loaded')
  var myexpr = ["+3*x*x","+4*x","+5"];
  var expr = "";
  for(s in myexpr)
  {
    expr += myexpr[s];
  }
  expr = "y = "+expr
  setH1Text(expr);
  
  myEval(expr,"x = 1");
}

function setH1Text(text)
{
  document.getElementById('jenish').innerHTML = text;
}

function myEval( ex,  ex1)
{
  var evaltobeexecuted  = ex1+";"+ex
  
  eval(evaltobeexecuted)
  setH1Text(y);
  //alert(y)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1 id="jenish">Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Note** : you need to place some substitution that x = 2 passing to second expression in myEval function. ultimately you can also build like I have built main expression `expr`.

**Caution** : Use of Eval is evil. It casues security issues like cross site scripting.

You can also make use of Math.js (**I highly recommend** this to you just use that have already build if possible :))

```js
function myFunc()
{
  var scope = {
  x: 2
  };
    
    var f = math.eval('f(x) = 3x^2+4x+5', scope);
    alert(f(2));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/1.3.0/math.js"></script>
<body onload="myFunc()">
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some regular expression education. This still won't solve for `x`, but it's worth looking at:

```
function youreWelcome(str, x){
  return str.replace(new RegExp('('+x+')', 'g'), '*$1').replace(new RegExp('('+x+')\\^(\\d)+', 'g'), function(m, p1, p2){
    var r = [];
    for(var i=0; i<p2; i++){
      r.push(p1);
    }
    return r.join('*');
  });
}
console.log(youreWelcome('3x^2+4x+5', 'x'));
console.log(youreWelcome('7n^3+42n^5+8', 'n'));
```

Look into `Math.pow()` when you're trying to solve for `x`.

Check this out:

[JavaScript: Calculate the nth root of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308627/javascript-calculate-the-nth-root-of-a-number)