# How to find the cube root of a negative integer such that it does not return NaN?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I have tried to find the cube root of a negative integer, for example, -1, without success.

I have used (-1) ** (1/3), but this returns a NaN. I thought that this might have something to do with type of the (1/3) fraction, but using (1/3 :: Double) yielded no success either.

As a result, my question is how can one find the cube root of -1 using Haskell so that it doesn't return NaN?

Comment: See https://wiki.haskell.org/Power_function

Comment: Both Haskell and Python return the first complex root of `-1` (~0.5-0.866i) -- I guess most programming languages do that as well, provided one uses a suitable complex type. When using doubles, NaN arises since the result is not real.

Answer (score 5):

For real numbers, the Haskell operator `(**)` is only defined for negative base (left-hand side) values when the exponent (right-hand side) is integer-valued.  If this strikes you as strange, note that the C function `pow` behaves the same way:

```
printf("%f\n", pow(-1.0, 1.0/3.0));   // prints "-nan", for me
```

and so does Python's `**` operator:

```
print((-1.0)**(1.0/3.0)) 
# gives: ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to fractional power
```

The problem is partially a mathematical one.  The "correct answer" for raising a negative base to a non-integral power is far from obvious.  See, for example, this [question on the Mathematics SO](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers).

If you *only* need a cube root that can handle negative numbers, the other answers given should work fine, except that @Istvan's answer should use `signum` instead of `sign`, like this:

```
cbrt x = signum x * abs x ** (1/3)
```

If you want a more general integral root function for real numbers, be warned that for even `n`, there are no nth roots of negative numbers that are real, so this is about the best you can do:

```
-- | Calculate nth root of b
root :: (Integral n, RealFloat b) => n -> b -> b
root n b | odd n && b < 0  = - abs b ** overn
         | otherwise       = b ** overn
    where overn = 1 / fromIntegral n
```

This gives:

```
> root 3 (-8)
-2.0
> root 4 (-8)
NaN      -- correct, as no real root exists
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Haskell, but you can do something like this:
sign(x) * abs(x) ** (1/3)

Answer (score 1):

On ghci I've done something that seems to solve your problem:

```
let cbrt x = if x < 0 then -((-x) ** (1/3)) else x ** (1/3)
```

A simple cuberoot function.

As I'm still learning I don't know if this is a proper solution, so please let me know if there's something missing or wrong ;)