# nth roots in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I was working on a simple little math project that is intended to help with exponential functions and stuff. I want to calculate `a` from `f(x)`, `x` and `c`. So the Formula for that is pretty simple, it's just the `x` **root** of `f(x)` **divided** by `c`. But I can't find a way to take a specific `nth` **root**. I read something about `Math.pow()` and played around with it, but can't really get it working.

Those are my current lines of code:

```
if (fx != null && c != null && x != null) {
var a = <the part i need>
aoutp.innerHTML = "a = " + a;
}
```

Hope you understand what I need :)

Comment: I recommend not using names like `a` and `c` and `fx` for variables. You should use descriptive names that better depict what they are doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308627/javascript-calculate-the-nth-root-of-a-number

Comment: I get what u mean, but that are the correct mathematical names for these. So everybody who understands maths and can help me will probably get what i am talking about. @Jeff B

Comment: @Zuckerpapa I understand, there is a general push that when you convert math to code that you also adhere to proper naming conventions as well. It will server you well.

Comment: _“I read something about Math.pow() and played around with it, but cant really get it working.”_ — But that’s exactly what you need. Why not show exactly what you’ve tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.pow(x, 1/y)` is `y`-root of `x`:

```js
const pow_4 = Math.pow(2, 4) // 2^4
console.log(pow_4) // 16

const sqrt_4 = Math.pow(pow_4, 1/4) // sqrt root lvl 4 of 16
console.log(sqrt_4) // 2
```

Comment: So if i get this right, i need to do: var a = Math.pow(fx/c, 1/x) to get the x-root of fx divided by c right? Because i did this and it just says "Infinity" no matter what the input is.

Comment: @Zuckerpapa `Math.pow(fx/c, 1/x)` is _ˣ_ √( _fx_ ∕ _c_). Is that what you need? Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Yes it is. I gave it the inputs fx = 1000, c = 500 and x = 5. It should output 1,15 (if rounded) but as i said, it outputs Infinity instead.

Comment: @Zuckerpapa `Math.pow(1000 / 500, 1 / 5)` is `1.148698354997035`. Again, please try using the [debugging capabilities](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser to confirm that `fx`, `x`, and `c` are the values you expect.

Comment: @Zuckerpapa It's not `NaN` your code must be incorrect somewhere. Don't you have something like this: `Math.pow(1000/500/1/5)` or `Math.pow(1000/500.1/5)`?

Comment: @ulou i used console.log() to output the given numbers in the console and for some reasons everything is fine except of x being <empty string> instead. Guess i have to go bug hunting -_- Anyways thx for the support